# Trying to import defined functions from a .py file into my environment and get answers, but receive NameError

Tags: python

I have a .py file with two functions inside. One calculates area and the other calculates perimeter. If they are important, these are the codes:

```
import math

def area(num):
    r = radius
    ans = math.pi*(r**2)
    return ans
    
def perimeter(num):
    r = radius
    ans2 = 2*math.pi*r
    return ans2
```

In the file I am trying to use them in, I am having a user enter a radius. It is then entered into each of the functions to get the area and perimeter. But I keep getting a Name Error. This is the code I wrote in the environment I'm working in:

```
from Circle import area

import math

radius = float(input('What is the radius of your circle: '))

print(area(radius))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your directory structure, and what are the names of your files? Without full context it is hard to diagnose your problem, which is not in the code you have presented.

Comment: The parameter that the `area()` function receives is named `num`.  It doesn't know anything about a variable named `radius`.  (Same problem with `perimeter()`, too.)

Comment: The file containing my functions is Circle.py.
In my current environment I have written 'from Circle import area'

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `r = radius` in your functions with `r=num` and it should work, if you are importing the file correctly.

The variable radius is not defined in your circle module and hence you are getting a NameError

Comment: This didn't seem to work. I just got the same message as before.

Comment: So if in Circle.py I have:

import math

def area(num):
    r = radius
    ans = math.pi*(r**2)
    return ans
    
def perimeter(num):
    r = radius
    ans2 = 2*math.pi*r
    return ans2

radius = float(input('What is your radius? '))

It should work?